# How did Osyraa and Emerald Chain learn about the Spore Drive?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In the S03E11 of *Star Trek: Discovery*,

> Osyraa captured USS Discovery along with its crew. She did that by first capturing and hacking Stamets directly inside Spore Cube. She was also confident that activating Spore Drive wouldn't destroy her attached ship and instead transport it through mycelial network.

But, for all that she needed to know inner workings of the Spore Drive. How did she learn such a well-kept secret? How did she even learn that the name of mysterious technology was Spore Drive?

Comment: Might be worth making it clear you're referring to S3 E11 - Su'Kal... and another question to consider - how did  she even know where Discovery was and manage to turn up so promptly...

Comment: I really hope that all of that was a trap for Osyraa - otherwise, the Federation is so retarted that they do not deserve to exist.

Comment: S03E10, ~43min "... but using Chain technology on a Star Fleet ship, it's a stretch." ... "Did it occur to either you that using this tech could compromise Discovery's systems?" ... "Osyraa is desperate for dilithium; Discovery has a Spore drive. It's not a good combination and you'll have to be exceptionally careful at all times." – Charles Vance, commander in chief of Starfleet. Earlier in that episode they learn how to amplify signals in subspace and start broadcasting. It's a big kick me sign. That being said, probably Lorca.

Comment: The "not a good combination" quote is repeated in E11's, *Last time on...*

Comment: @Mazura Whao!!!

Comment: The season isn't over yet.

Comment: "Speaking at a Q+A for DragonCon, Jason ‘plead the fifth’ when quizzed about the resurrection of the character" - If Jason Isaacs is still on the payroll, I'll give you three guesses.

Comment: @Mazura Well, he didn't come back for earlier mirror universe episodes.